# Docker info and Docker ps show different number of running containers

Tags: docker, docker-for-mac

If I run `docker info` I get:

```
Containers: 75
 Running: 11
 Paused: 0
 Stopped: 64
Images: 99
```

If I run `docker ps` I get a list of 8 containers:

```
docker ps -q

e5a10f8cf5c9
c1e317d3a423
062e783b33e9
66cfa6e2c1c5
ed409b327484
ed4135c25573
b5151b422e8a
1a9abcdb0342
```

What gives?  This is on a Mac, and here's my whole info:

```
Containers: 75
 Running: 11
 Paused: 0
 Stopped: 64
Images: 99
Server Version: 18.03.1-ce
Storage Driver: overlay2
 Backing Filesystem: extfs
 Supports d_type: true
 Native Overlay Diff: true
Logging Driver: json-file
Cgroup Driver: cgroupfs
Plugins:
 Volume: local
 Network: bridge host ipvlan macvlan null overlay
 Log: awslogs fluentd gcplogs gelf journald json-file logentries splunk syslog
Swarm: active
 NodeID: daldy4p8ynukd4mlf9p1wv1vx
 Is Manager: true
 ClusterID: hccuyor98zeifze8mexdc4uw0
 Managers: 1
 Nodes: 1
 Orchestration:
  Task History Retention Limit: 5
 Raft:
  Snapshot Interval: 10000
  Number of Old Snapshots to Retain: 0
  Heartbeat Tick: 1
  Election Tick: 3
 Dispatcher:
  Heartbeat Period: 5 seconds
 CA Configuration:
  Expiry Duration: 3 months
  Force Rotate: 0
 Autolock Managers: false
 Root Rotation In Progress: false
 Node Address: 192.168.65.2
 Manager Addresses:
  192.168.65.2:2377
Runtimes: runc
Default Runtime: runc
Init Binary: docker-init
containerd version: 773c489c9c1b21a6d78b5c538cd395416ec50f88
runc version: 4fc53a81fb7c994640722ac585fa9ca548971871
init version: 949e6fa
Security Options:
 seccomp
  Profile: default
Kernel Version: 4.9.87-linuxkit-aufs
Operating System: Docker for Mac
OSType: linux
Architecture: x86_64
CPUs: 4
Total Memory: 1.952GiB
Name: linuxkit-025000000001
ID: WYFW:3ASR:IA6F:7GF7:X6SH:SX4J:SXOC:B73V:GJFE:T4SG:K3EQ:2FOR
Docker Root Dir: /var/lib/docker
Debug Mode (client): false
Debug Mode (server): true
 File Descriptors: 100
 Goroutines: 236
 System Time: 2018-06-14T16:33:44.026321217Z
 EventsListeners: 6
HTTP Proxy: docker.for.mac.http.internal:3128
HTTPS Proxy: docker.for.mac.http.internal:3129
Registry: https://index.docker.io/v1/
Labels:
Experimental: true
Insecure Registries:
 127.0.0.0/8
Live Restore Enabled: false
```

Comment: How many containers do you have that are only created? `docker ps -aqf status=created`

Answer (score 0):

For some reason docker info shows outdated information. Maybe cached somehow. 
If you actually restart docker e.g. `systemctl restart docker` the `docker info` will give you the same amount of running containers like `docker ps` does